# In Ruby On Rails, I get "undefined method" error from a file that is being included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I am working with Ruby On Rails 4, and working with RefineryCMS. Officially, RefineryCMS only works with Rails 3.2 but on Github the core team has said that the newest version of RefineryCMS should work with Rails 4.

I needed to add some custom instance methods, so I copied the file:

```
cp vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-c8d8680bd4f5/pages/lib/refinery/pages/instance_methods.rb  lib/refinery/pages/
```

Perhaps this was a bit lazy of me, but I was thinking this would be fast. I then added a method, and called it in the template, but I got undefined method" error. In this file:

```
app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb
```

I currently have this code:

```
                <div class="col-sm-24">
                    <%= Refinery::Pages::MenuPresenter.new(refinery_menu_pages, self).to_html %>
                </div>

                <%= SubMenuPresenter.new(build_sub_menu_pages(@current_sub_menu_pages), self).to_html %>
```

and in instance_methods.rb, I currently have this code:

```
  def refinery_menu_pages
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "
    puts " hi "

    Menu.new Page.fast_menu
  end

  def build_sub_menu_pages(current_sub_menu_pages)
    puts " inside of  build_sub_menu_pages "
    Menu.new current_sub_menu_pages
  end
```

I can see all of the "hi"s in the terminal, so I know this file is being read.

SubMenuPresenter is simply defined as:

```
class SubMenuPresenter < Refinery::Pages::MenuPresenter
end
```

I will eventually customize the HTML/CSS, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

The error is:

```
undefined method `build_sub_menu_pages'
```

and it points at this line in the template:

```
<%= SubMenuPresenter.new(build_sub_menu_pages(@current_sub_menu_pages), self).to_html %>
```

But how can the method not be seen if the method just above is seen, as proven by the "hi"s that show up in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid. I missed this:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :refinery_menu_pages
    base.send :alias_method_chain, :render, :presenters
  end
```

So I added build_sub_menu_pages:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :refinery_menu_pages, :build_sub_menu_pages
    base.send :alias_method_chain, :render, :presenters
  end
```

That fixed the problem.